# DataFrame of soccer soccers into a league table

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

so I'm going to re-write this question having spent some time trying to crack it today, and I think I'm doing okay so far.

I have a soccer results database with this as the head(3)

```
      Date Season     home           visitor   FT  hgoal  vgoal  division  tier  totgoal  goaldif result
1993-04-12   1992  Arsenal       Aston Villa  0-1      0      1         1     1        1       -1      A  
1992-09-12   1992  Arsenal  Blackburn Rovers  0-1      0      1         1     1        1       -1      A  
1992-10-03   1992  Arsenal           Chelsea  2-1      2      1         1     1        3        1      H
```

I've written this code, which work:

```
def my_table(season) :
    teams = season['home'].unique().tolist()
    table = []
    for team in teams :
        home = season[season['home'] == team]['result']
        hseq = dict(zip(*np.unique(home, return_counts=True)))

        away = season[season['visitor'] == team]['result']
        aseq = dict(zip(*np.unique(away, return_counts=True)))

        team_dict = {
            "season"   : season.iloc[0]['Season'],
            "team"     : team,
            "home_pl"  : sum(hseq.values()),            
            "home_w"   : hseq.get('H', 0),
            "home_d"   : hseq.get('D', 0),
            "home_l"   : hseq.get('A', 0),
            "home_gf"  : season[season['home'] == team]['hgoal'].sum(),
            "home_ga"  : season[season['home'] == team]['vgoal'].sum(),
            "home_gd"  : season[season['home'] == team]['goaldif'].sum(),
            "home_pts" : hseq.get('H', 0) * 3 + hseq.get('D', 0),
            "away_pl"  : sum(aseq.values()), 
            "away_w"   : aseq.get('A', 0),
            "away_d"   : aseq.get('D', 0),
            "away_l"   : aseq.get('H', 0),
            "away_gf"  : season[season['visitor'] == team]['vgoal'].sum(),
            "away_ga"  : season[season['visitor'] == team]['hgoal'].sum(),
            "away_gd"  : (season[season['visitor'] == team]['goaldif'].sum() * -1),
            "away_pts" : aseq.get('A', 0) * 3 + hseq.get('D', 0)
        }
        team_dict["pl"]  = team_dict["home_pl"]  + team_dict['away_pl']            
        team_dict["w"]   = team_dict["home_w"]   + team_dict['away_w']            
        team_dict["d"]   = team_dict["home_d"]   + team_dict['away_d']            
        team_dict["l"]   = team_dict["home_l"]   + team_dict['away_l']
        team_dict["gf"]  = team_dict["home_gf"]  + team_dict['away_gf']
        team_dict["ga"]  = team_dict["home_ga"]  + team_dict['away_ga']
        team_dict["gd"]  = team_dict["home_gd"]  + team_dict['away_gd']
        team_dict["pts"] = team_dict["home_pts"] + team_dict['away_pts']
        table.append(team_dict)
    return table

seasons = pl['Season'].unique().tolist()
all_tables = []
for season in seasons :
    table = my_table(pl[pl['Season'] == season])
    all_tables += table

tbl = pd.DataFrame(all_tables) 

away = ['away_pl', 'away_w', 'away_d', 'away_l', 'away_gf', 'away_ga', 'away_gd', 'away_pts']
home = ['home_pl', 'home_w', 'home_d', 'home_l', 'home_gf', 'home_ga', 'home_gd', 'home_pts']
full = ['pl', 'w', 'd', 'l', 'gf', 'ga', 'gd', 'pts']
team = ['team']
tbl = tbl[['season', 'team']+home+away+full]
```

So now 'tbl' is good, and I can index it by season. But I'm having trouble making it a multi-index which is by 'season' first and then by their points total (descending) which would be equivalent to their league finishing position. To be clear, I want the index to be 1-20 (or 1-22) but the index be driven by the points total.

Also, if anyone has any thoughts on how I've gone about building the table itself, would love to hear it. I spent a long time trying to use various vectorized functions which I'm told are more efficient but couldn't get it to work and reverted to for loops.

Thank you

Comment: My first thought is that  you should provide some sample data and show us what you expect the results to look like.  Read these for guidance on how to ask a question  [HowToAsk](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared I have tried to edit and include that now

Comment: Have rewritten completely now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did used your code above to make it work...

```
team_count = tbl.groupby(['season'])['team'].count().tolist()
rank_column = []

for i in team_count :
    j = list(range(1,i+1,1))
    rank_column += j

tbl = tbl.sort_values(['season', 'pts', 'gd', 'gf'], ascending=[True, False, False, False])
tbl['rank'] = rank_column
tbl = tbl.set_index(['season', 'rank'])
```

Not sure if it's the most efficient way, but it worked?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [GroupBy.rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rank.html) or [Series.rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) to calculate teams by descending `pts` rank. Since I can not tell if your final dataframe is at season, team, or game level choose appropriate ranking:

```
tbl['team_rank'] = tbl.groupby(['season', 'team'])['pts'].rank(ascending=False)

tbl['team_rank'] = tbl['pts'].rank(ascending=False)
```

Then use `set_index` on the pair of fields for the multindex with no need for prior sorting.

```
tbl = tbl.set_index(['season', 'team_rank'])
```

However, since you require multiple fields for ranking purposes, consider using a `reset_index` then retrieve the `index.values` to get the ordered number (`+ 1` if you do not want to begin with zero):

```
tbl = tbl.sort_values(['season', 'pts', 'gd', 'gf'], 
                      ascending=[True, False, False, False]).reset_index(drop=True)
tbl['rank'] = tbl.index.values + 1
tbl = tbl.set_index(['season', 'rank'])
```

Comment: Hi, so the 'pts' column is already the team's total points for that season - I think the extra column I need to create is one that ranks the teams from 1-20 after sorting by ['season','pts'], do you know if there's an easy way to do that?

Comment: I knew I misread your needs. The word *rank* was never used until your comment here. See my update using `rank`.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear and thanks a lot for your help. The rank() method is a good one to learn. In this case, I stuck with the little for loop I write because I wanted it to rank by ['season', 'pts', 'gd', 'gf'] going down the list whenever there were ties.

Comment: I see. See my extended answer using `reset_index` and `index.values` to void the `for` loop.

Comment: So that works for 1 season, but the reason I need the for loop is because I need to reset the index for every season. i.e. if there's two season, the rank column will be 1-20 for season 1 and then 1-20 for season 2.

Comment: Reconsider `groupby.rank` but to avoid ties, add up *pts*, *gd*, *gf* then rank order descending grouped by season: `tbl.groupby(['season'])['pts_plus_gd_plus_gf'].rank(ascending=False)`. Would have helped to see fuller data set. Sample was not enough to know the team and season variability.

Comment: Thank for all your help, and I'll try that. Also apologies for not including a fuller data set, will do so next time. I'm still new to this :)